# converting camelCase strings to underscore in dart language

Tags: string, flutter, dart

in java 9 we can simply convert `camelCase` to underscore like `camel_case`

```
String text = "camelCase";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?<=[a-z])[A-Z]").matcher(text);
String result = m.replaceAll(match -> "_" + match.group().toLowerCase());
```

now my question is whats equivalent of this code in dart?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use **RegExp** and the method **replaceAllMapped**:

```
String text = 'camelCase';
final exp = RegExp('(?<=[a-z])[A-Z]');
String result = text.replaceAllMapped(exp, (m) => '_${m.group(0)}').toLowerCase();
```

Comment: Mind that Safari doesn't support [lookbehind](https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind) yet (`?<=`), so that regex won't work in all the browsers if you are using Flutter web.

Answer (score 7):

Don't reinvent code if there is already a package for this :

Github: https://github.com/Ephenodrom/Dart-Basic-Utils
Pub Dev : https://pub.dev/packages/basic_utils

Install :

```
dependencies:
  basic_utils: ^1.5.1
```

Usage :

```dart
String result = StringUtils.camelCaseToLowerUnderscore("camelCase");
print(result); // camel_case
```

Other usefull methods from the StringUtils Class :

```dart
String defaultString(String str, {String defaultStr = ''});
bool isNullOrEmpty(String s);
bool isNotNullOrEmpty(String s);
String camelCaseToUpperUnderscore(String s);
String camelCaseToLowerUnderscore(String s);
bool isLowerCase(String s);
bool isUpperCase(String s);
bool isAscii(String s);
String capitalize(String s);
String reverse(String s);
int countChars(String s, String char, {bool caseSensitive = true});
bool isDigit(String s);
bool equalsIgnoreCase(String a, String b);
bool inList(String s, List<String> list, {bool ignoreCase = false});
bool isPalindrome(String s);
String hidePartial(String s, {int begin = 0, int end, String replace = "*"});
String addCharAtPosition(String s, String char, int position,{bool repeat = false});
```